# WPF .net 4.6.2 TextBoxView ThrottleBackgroundTasksForUserInput memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I am encountering a memory leak in my application.

This leak seems to occur with any TextBox.
TextBox utilizes a internal class called TextBoxView for various rendering machinations I believe.
It is this TextBoxView class in which I am witnessing the leak.

Specifically the TextBoxView's implementation of ITextView.ThrottleBackgroundTasksForUserInput method.

The TextBoxView contains a DispatchTimer.
When this TextBoxView class handles a TextInputEvent from the TextBox, usually by a user having clicked in the textbox and the cursor flashing within, the ThrottleBackgroundTasksForUserInput method is called.

This method looks like this (Decompiled with dotPeek)

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: System.Windows.Controls.TextBoxView
// Assembly: PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
// MVID: 36701698-F977-4C53-AA54-82CF7DE99544
// Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll
void ITextView.ThrottleBackgroundTasksForUserInput()
{
  if (this._throttleBackgroundTimer == null)
  {
    this._throttleBackgroundTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Background);
    this._throttleBackgroundTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
    this._throttleBackgroundTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.OnThrottleBackgroundTimeout);
  }
  else
    this._throttleBackgroundTimer.Stop();
  this._throttleBackgroundTimer.Start();
}
```

As we can see the Tick Event of the DispatchTimer is subscribed to.
Unfortunately, the event is never unsubscribed from, however the DispatchTimer is stopped when the user clicks somewhere else outside the textbox, but it appears there is a caveat to that.

If I have the cursor flashing in the textbox and then close the dialog window that textbox exists in, the entire dialog is leaked via DependencyProperty effective value craziness. I have to make this click to close the window very quickly, and if I hold the mouse left button down long enough over the close button before releasing, the TextBox apparently loses focus or the timer expires and the timeout is called, and the TextBoxView instance is removed, resulting in no leak.

It's an extremely strange behavior.
I have no fix for it yet, and would be curious what the community would suggest?
My immediate thought would be to clear focus and process all messages above Application.Idle priority before continuing with the window close via a Window.Closing handler on the dialog.

Any input into the issue would be most appreciated.

Edit: Added screenshot of dotMemory retention path.
[image: Retention Path]

Edit: Adding a bit of new information here.

Changing focus doesn't seem to do anything. The timer's already started, and the implementation of the TextBoxView is such that it must complete for the DispatchTimer to be stopped.

It appears as actually delaying for 2 seconds, using a new thread sleep and dispatcherframe in the dialog's unloaded event makes the issue go away.
This allows the TextBoxView's timer to time out and stop.

I'm not a fan of this solution though.
Waiting for 2 seconds introduces a noticeable hitch in performance where there shouldn't be any during a simple dialog close.

Another hacky solution would be to trawl the visual tree, find all text box views, and reflectively stop their DispatchTimer.

Comment: Which GCRoot holds the "leaked" dialog?

Comment: Not sure at the moment. If dotmemory can help me find that out i'll get it to you. I do call a GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced); combo with WaitForPendingFinalizers() a couple methods up the callstack after the the dialog is closed and my reference to is has been nulled.

Comment: I have added a screenshot with the retention path of the TextBoxView